# 0x80131904 ASP.NET error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Okay, funky error codes.

So I got the above error after sending my website live on a server. Other websites are live on the same server using IIS. I'm using SQL Express.

Looking online says things such as "Use instance name" and "Check your connection string" all of which works. Furthermore, I have a back-end application attached to the same database which has no trouble getting data from it.

Any thoughts? If that isn't enough to go on feel free to ask for more details.

Relevant code below:

```
 // Redirect to noKey page if we can't find a key


                          if (Request["key"] == null)
                Response.Redirect("NoKey.html", true);

            // Get some Course info

            string first_name, last_name, email, telephone, course;
            DateTime date;



            using (var server = Connection.LTMConnection())
            using (var command = server.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM Keys INNER JOIN Courses ON Keys.course = Courses.id WHERE [key] = @key";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", Request["key"]);

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    if (!reader.Read())
                        // No Key
                        Response.Redirect("NoKey.html", true);

                    first_name = reader["first_name"].ToString();
                    last_name = reader["last_name"].ToString();
                    email = reader["email"].ToString();
                    telephone = reader["telephone"].ToString();
                    course = reader["name"].ToString();
                    date = reader["date"] as DateTime? ?? DateTime.Now;

                    if (DateTime.Compare(date, DateTime.Today) < 0)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("Expired.html", true);
                    }

                }
            }

            PrefaceName.Text = first_name + " " + last_name;
            PrefaceCourse.Text = course;

            // Populate specialism fields

            using (var server = Connection.LTMConnection())
            using (var command = server.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM FormSpecialism";

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var panel = new Panel();
                        panel.CssClass = "table_3rd";

                        var checkbox = new CheckBox();
                        checkbox.Text = reader["text"].ToString();
                        SpecialismMapping.Add(panel, reader["text"].ToString());

                        panel.Controls.Add(checkbox);

                        DataSpecialismPanel.Controls.Add(panel);
                    }
                }
            }
            using (var server = Connection.LTMConnection())
            using (var command = server.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM FormClientObj";

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var panel = new Panel();
                        panel.CssClass = "table_3rd";

                        var checkbox = new CheckBox();
                        checkbox.Text = reader["text"].ToString();
                        ClientObjMapping.Add(panel, reader["text"].ToString());

                        panel.Controls.Add(checkbox);

                        DataClientObjPanel.Controls.Add(panel);
                    }
                }
            }
            using (var server = Connection.LTMConnection())
            using (var command = server.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM FormPOSItems";

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var panel = new Panel();
                        panel.CssClass = "table_3rd";

                        var checkbox = new CheckBox();
                        checkbox.Text = reader["text"].ToString();
                        POSMapping.Add(panel, reader["text"].ToString());

                        panel.Controls.Add(checkbox);

                        DataPOSItemsPanel.Controls.Add(panel);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DataQualifications.Text = ex.ToString();
            //Response.Redirect("NoKey.html", true);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Connection string for both back-end and website is as follows(with some details omitted)

```
public static readonly string LTM = @"
        Data Source =portal.omit.com\SQLEXPRESS; 
        Initial Catalog = OmitTrainingManager;  
        User Id = LTM; 
        Password = OMIT;";
```

Comment: Are IIS, SQL express and your backend application all running on the same computer?

Comment: IIS and SQL Express are on a server, the back-end runs on a shared drive which can access the server. The back end is doing fine, just the website can't seem to access the Database which is on the same server as the website

Comment: Could you post your connection string of both backend application and the web project.

Comment: hmm, i think you just have to secure that the back-end's connection string is exactly the same with the ASP.NET site's connection string. I just don't know how you locate your connection string, through web.config? registry? well either way, your application CAN'T see the connection string / has in-correct connection. I suggest you display your connection string on a label for the mean time so you know what your site is using.

Comment: Sorry, should have added, I have specified the name in web.config too. That edit above shows the string in the c# code for the website, but I noticed IIS has an area for connection strings se specified it there too - no change though.